# Guess the secret word

Tags: word, visual

Can you find the secret word in the following image?

[image]

Comment: Is it just me, or I could see the answer right away?

Comment: @PierrePaquette no, it's not just you

Comment: I guess our brain is a powerful tool that can see patterns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to

> rearrange the horizontal stripes

to get

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> Stripes?

Explanation

> Switching tiles in each column then squishing them together would make that. At least in my imagination.